# C# LINQ SQL EntityFramework challenge

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have (in this context) 3 tables that contain products, properties and property types.
In one of the front-end cases I need to grab lists of distinct properties based on previously selected values of different property types.

For example;
All products have 3 properties of property types 'width', 'height' and 'diameter'.
Based on selections I need to return lists of properties of types 'width', 'height' and 'diameter'. I've selected a width of, lets say, 100 and I want to grab all properties of property type 'height' which have products with 'width' properties of 100.

It's a bit tricky to explain but I hope this is somewhat clear.

Products:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
    [ProductId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [SupplierId] [int] NULL,
    [BrandId] [int] NULL,
    [ProductDiscountGroupId] [int] NULL,
    [VATProductPostingGroupId] [int] NULL,
    [PromotionTypeId] [int] NULL,
    [LocationId] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [Description2] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [Description3] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [Description4] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    ...
    )
```

Properties:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductProperty](
    [ProductPropertyId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductPropertyTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductPropertyLookupId] [int] NULL,
    [Unit] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DecimalValue] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [BooleanValue] [bit] NULL,
    [TextValue] [varchar](100) NULL,
    ...
    )
```

Property types:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductPropertyType](
    [ProductPropertyTypeId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Priority] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UOM] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PropertyType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Visible] [bit] NOT NULL,
    ...
    )
```

Comment: You should try to give your question a more descriptive title - maybe something like "Selecting from a table based on data from two other tables"? I'm not sure I quite understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to select all propertys for a given height/width?

```
int creteria = 100 


var = from ptype in ProductPropertyType 
      join prop in ProductProperty on ptype.ProductPropertyId  = prop.ProductPropertyId
      where (prop.Unit == creteria && ptype.Name == "Height") || (prop.Unit == creteria && ptype.Name == "Width") 
      Select prop
```

I haven't tested that the linq will work 100% but is this the type of thing you are after?

Edit 1

Hi not sure if you have solved this since but I have had another go at the Linq. There is probably a better way to do this and I cant guarantee this will give you the exact output your after. let know know if this works for you.

```
    var AllWidthProperties = from p in ProductProperty
                             where p.Name == "Width"
                             select p;

    var AllProducstWtihHeightOfValue = from p in ProductProperty 
                                       where p.Name == "Height" && p.Unit == creteria
                                       join Prod in Product on Prod.ProductId equals p.ProductId
                                       group Prod by Prod.ProductId into g
                                       select new
                                       {
                                           ProductId = g.Key
                                       };

    var SelectedWithProperties = from p in AllWidthProperties 
                                 join Prod in AllProducstWtihHeightOfValue on Prod.ProductId equals p.ProductId
                                 select p;
```

Comment: I'm trying to select all width properties for products that also have properties of type height with value x.